# How can I disable break line prettier

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, eslint, prettier

My printWidth value is 200 and the like breaking every time for example.

```
<Form.Item label="xxx"><Input /></Form.Item>
<Form.Item label="yyy"><Select /></Form.Item>
<Form.Item label="zzzz"><Input /></Form.Item>
```

When i run in this code block the eslint result is

```
<Form.Item label="xxx">
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
<Form.Item label="yyy">
  <Select />
</Form.Item>
<Form.Item label="zzzz">
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

I don't want to break line if printWidth wasn't max. How can i block it ?

**Eslint rules.**

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb-typescript-prettier'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/components/global/context_menu/*"],
  rules: {
    "radix": 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    'react/button-has-type': 'off',
    'no-use-before-define': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 'off',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/alt-text': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'comma-dangle': 'off',
    'consistent-this': [0, 'component'],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias': 'off',
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 'off',
    'no-self-compare': 'off',
    'react/require-default-props': 'off',
    'no-return-assign': 'off',
    'react/destructuring-assignment': 'off',
    camelcase: 'off',
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control":"off",
    'prefer-destructuring': 'off',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps':'off',
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events':'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions':'off',
    'no-throw-literal': 'off',
    'no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs': 'off',
    'no-tabs': 'off',
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 'off',
    'no-underscore-dangle': 'off',
    'import/no-cycle': 'off',
    'max-len': [2, 150, 2],
  },
};
```

**Prettier rules.**

```
module.exports = {
    singleQuote: true,
    trailingComma: 'all',
    printWidth: 200,
    arrowParens:"always"
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the prettier to style a part of your code you just need to do this: (that prettier ignore comment)

```
{/* prettier-ignore */}
<Form.Item label="xxx"><Input /></Form.Item>
```

this is based on the docs:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

hope this helps

Comment: I cant put everywhere this code block man.

Comment: Well actually the prettier docs HAS SUGGESTED NOT TO use prettier the way you want to use it. https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html look they said:

In other words, don’t try to use printWidth as if it was ESLint’s max-len – they’re not the same. max-len just says what the maximum allowed line length is, but not what the generally preferred length is – which is what printWidth specifies.